# Swagger PHP Object instead of Array

Tags: swagger-php

Example swagger markup for a model

```
* @SWG\Model(
 * id="UserSubscriptionSearchResultsFilter",
 *  @SWG\Property(name="total", type="integer"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="perPage", type="integer"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="query", type="string"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="sortColumn", type="string"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="sortDirection", type="string"),
 * )
 */

/**
 * @SWG\Model(
 * id="UserSubscriptionSearchResults",
 *  @SWG\Property(name="results",type="array", items="$ref:UserSubscriptionRepository"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="total", type="integer"),
 *  @SWG\Property(name="filter",type="object", uniqueItems="$ref:UserSubscriptionSearchResultsFilter")
 * )
 */
```

Right now the schema looks like:

```
"filter": "object"
```

Instead what I want to see is:

```
"filter":  {
        "total": 0,
        "perPage": 0,
        "query": "",
        "sortColumn": "",
        "sortDirection": ""
      }
```

Right now I've only been able to create an array object that looks relatively similar to this, but it is still not full spec.

I've read similar issues here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/38
https://github.com/mission-liao/pyswagger/issues/18

But I've not found a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct schema in Swagger 2.0 is in your case should be something like:

```
"definitions": {
  "filter": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
       "total": {
          "type": "integer"
       },
       "perPage": {
          "type": "integer"
       },
       "query": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "sortColumn": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "sortDirection": {
          "type": "string"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the project you use is [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php).
Here is a quote from their example for declaring a model from [here](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore.swagger.io/models/Category.php):

```
<?php
namespace PetstoreIO;
/**
 * @SWG\Definition(
 *   @SWG\Xml(name="Category")
 * )
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @SWG\Property(format="int64")
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @SWG\Property()
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;
}
```

The terms are changed from "model" to "definition" when upgrading from 1.2 to 2.0.